# Fetch data from models related with foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have one model which is related to `User model` with `Foreign key` :

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user        = models.ForeignKey(User)
    gender      = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    credits     = models.IntegerField()
    ...
```

Now I want to fetch user data and for this I did like this :

```
profile = user.userprofile_set.select_related()
```

Now from profile variable I have all data which is in `UserProfile` model but not from `User` model **e.g.,** I have `gender , credits` etc but not `user email, name` etc. which comes from `User` model.But I want all user related information , I know `request` parameter will have `User instance` but later I may face the same problem for other models related with Foreign key.

So Please let me know the best way to fetch `User` data related with `Foreign key` in best suitable way.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use this :

```
profile = UserProfile.objects.select_related('user').get(pk = <pk of userprofile instance>)
```

It won't execute second query on when you fetch data from `user` table like this :

```
print profile.user.email ## Won't execute second query
```

Now you can get all or specific fields using `model_to_dict`

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict
print model_to_dict(profile.user, fields=[], exclude=[]) ## All information of user relation.
```

Comment: It gives the error 'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta' , I think its because model_to_dict() needs object and profile is not an object also select_related cannot be used with get() and I need to fetch profile for particuler use and If I user filter() for that the same error comes .

Comment: I think you can use `select_related` with `get()` . https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related

Comment: yeah , after select_related() not before , my mistake

Comment: Also I think I can access user info without model_to_dict() , like "profile" gives me data of UserProfile model and "profile.user" gives me User model data.